# Child dependant field in abstract class with Django's ORM

Tags: python, inheritance, django-models, django-orm

I have these two models:

```
class Interface(models.Model):
    # fields
class OldInterface(models.Model):
    interface = models.ForeignKey(_base,related_name='old_versions')
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Inherited by their "Spatial" and "Functional" variants :

```
class SpatialInterface(Interface):
    # fields
class OldSpatialInterface(OldInterface):
    _base = SpatialInterface

class FunctionalInterface(Interface):
    # fields
class OldFunctionalInterface(OldInterface):
    _base = FunctionalInterface
```

Of course my code fails, because _base is not defined in the parent Model.

My question is : Is there any way, or trick to tell the ForeignKey to read to the target model from the child Model ?

Or more generally, is there any way, to, in the parent class, dynamically read a variable located in the child class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my researches, I think that this is not possible, because of the way syncdb parses the models.py : `__init__()` is **not** called and so I didn't find any way to dynamically set the ForeignKey target based on the child.